# How the get the current day name using particular date in android?

Tags: android

I have date string 18-2-2012 , from this how to get the current day name i.e., today is "**saturday**" like this. for tomorrow's date 19-2-2012 and the day name is "**sunday**".

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use java date formats.

```
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = inFormat.parse(input);
SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
String goal = outFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use Calendar

```
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.setTime(date_your_want_to_know);

            String[] days = new String[] { "SUNDAY", "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY" }

            String day = days[calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)];
```

Comment: String[] days = new String[] {"", "SUNDAY", "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY" }

Comment: String day = days[calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)];
we should chage above line to 
String day = days[calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1];
//because array of index start from 0

Comment: SUNDAY is not always the first day

Answer (score 11):

Just use a single line of code:

```
android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEEE", date);
```

Comment: This is the best approach in my opinion. Does exactly what the author of the question asked for and is a single line.

Answer (score 3):

```
int dayOfWeek=bday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);  // Returns 3, for Tuesday!
```

for more detail go here....
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java_android_date-and-time/

Answer (score 0):

First convert the date string to a Date using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Then make a `Calendar` instance from that date.

Finally, retrieve the day of week from the `Calendar` using the `get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`. This will give you an integer between 1 to 7 representing the day of the week. You can simple map this to an array of Strings to get the days.

Answer (score 0):

On @vivek's answer add **"-1"** at `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`, since it returns numbers from 1 to 7 but the String array is indexed from 0 to 6.

```
calendar.setTime(date_your_want_to_know);

String[] days = new String[] { "SUNDAY", "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY" }

String day = days[calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Hope it will work.
This is worked for me.

```
public String daysNameOfWeek(String inputDate){

    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.UK);
    try {

        Date date = df.parse(inputDate.trim());
        SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
         daysName  = outFormat.format(date);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return daysName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
String dayToday = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEEE", date).toString();
TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myTextView.setText(dayToday);
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users refer to and eventually apply this knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score -1):

Below method will return the day by passing the date in String format.
null is returned if exception occurs.

```
private String getDay(String date_in_string_format){        
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
        Date date;
        try {
             date = df.parse(date_in_string_format);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error:","Exception " + e);
            return null;
        }
        return new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(date);
    }
```

Hope it helps.